# Simple linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, vector-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-simple_operator)

> a linear operator T on a finite-dimensional vector space is semi-simple if every T-invariant subspace has a complementary T-invariant subspace.

I wonder if there is a concept for a linear operator to be simple?  How is that defined?

Thanks!

Comment: A linear operator $T$ is simple if there are no $T$-invariant subspaces except $V$ and $\{0\}$. So "semi-simple'' means "direct sum of simples."